# Image could not be opened through Pygame's Image.load()

Tags: python-3.x, pygame-surface

My pygame program does not seems to load images. I tried image.load() by directly entering the image path as well by joining directories. I tried the code on Sublime Text as well as IDLE. 
File Source: C:\Users\Aich\Documents\PythonProjects\Trial
Image Source: C:\Users\Aich\Desktop\Sprite1.png
(I've currently kept image and file in different locations but keeping them at same location did not yield anything)

I am using Windows 8.1.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = (255, 255, 255)

x = 500
y = 400

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))

pygame.display.set_caption('Image')

image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Aich\Desktop\Sprite1.png').convert()

while True:
    display_surface.fill(white)
    display_surface.blit(image , (0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Are you getting any type of error or are you simply getting a blank display?

Comment: An error which displays "pygame.error couldn't load image from <path>"

Comment: Try putting `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` at the first 2 lines of your program. This will tell you what path you are starting from.

Comment: I will try what you are suggesting but I've already checked before my path by another os function